# Indeterminate expression 0(I*Infinity]) on indefinite integrals on first use only

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I do not know if this is new or not, I googled before.

Windows 7, 10.1 64 bit: Integrals generate this error message

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The strange thing also is that the message shows up the first time the command is made (in fresh kernel). Next time `Integrate` is evaluated, this message do not show up. In both cases the integral is returned unevaluated. (this takes 1-2 minutes to finish, but it does not hang)

```
ClearAll[a, b, c, d, e, x]; 
p2 = (c*e + d*e*x)^(3/2)*(a + b*ArcCosh[c + d*x])^3
Integrate[p2, x]
```

Also, The next time it finishes very fast. It seems the first time it is called, it caches some result that is why it returns fast but without the error message. Here is screen shot show showing the two calls:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Another example which generates the same error (multiple times) but this one takes much longer to finish (unevaluated, about 5 minutes on my PC).

```
ClearAll[a, b, c, d, e, x]; 
p3 = Sqrt[c*e + d*e*x]*(a + b*ArcCosh[c + d*x])^3;
Integrate[p3, x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Same error show up in version 9 as well.

What can cause this message to show up? Is this a bug?

Comment: Looks like a bug. I've reported it internally.